# Finding collision between two Images using virtual Rect

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a game. There is a turtle and lots of platforms it can walk on. It walks on its own and you can change the direction it is walking. I implemented a working logic, but I think it can be improved.

I made 2 classes (one for the turtle and one for the platforms).

```
class Turtle
{
    public Rect HitBox;
    public bool IsMoving;
    public bool IsDirectionForward;
    public double DistanceWalked;
    public double MetersFalled;
}

class Ground
{
    public Rect HitBox;
}
```

Then I created a virtual Rect that would simulate the right width and height of the ground and the turtle only after using **Inflate** function.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ground1 = new Ground();
    ground1.HitBox = new Rect(groundImg1.Margin.Left, groundImg1.Margin.Top, groundImg1.Width, groundImg1.Height);
    ground1.HitBox.Inflate(0, -35);

    zelvicka = new Turtle();
    zelvicka.IsMoving = true;
    zelvicka.IsDirectionForward = true;

    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20);
    timer.Tick += Update;
    timer.Start();
}
```

I've done the same with the turtle, whose virtual Rect is updating every time it moves in Update function generated by DispatcherTimer so the virtual Rect is always up to date.

```
    private void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        zelvicka.HitBox = new Rect(turtleImg.Margin.Left, turtleImg.Margin.Top, turtleImg.Width, turtleImg.Height);
        zelvicka.HitBox.Inflate(-110, -30);

        // ZELVICKA IS GOING FORWARD AND IS TOUCHING THE GROUND
        // ZELVICKA IS GOING BACKWARDS AND IS TOUCHING THE GROUND
        if (zelvicka.IsMoving && zelvicka.IsDirectionForward && zelvicka.HitBox.IntersectsWith(ground1.HitBox))
        {
            turtleImg.Margin = new Thickness(zelvicka.DistanceWalked += 3, zelvicka.MetersFalled, 0, 0);
        }
        else if (zelvicka.IsMoving && !zelvicka.IsDirectionForward && zelvicka.HitBox.IntersectsWith(ground1.HitBox))
        {
            turtleImg.Margin = new Thickness(zelvicka.DistanceWalked -= 3, zelvicka.MetersFalled, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Rate this code, please, and suggest improvements, if any.

Comment: It works properly, but I have to manually set new height and new width with Inflate function, which I found very ineffective and time-consuming, hence I'm looking for a better way as I don't think my code is good enough and it needs some more improvements!

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).